# converting a UYVY FFmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, directshow, video-processing

I want to read and show a video using opencv. I've recorded with Direct-show, the Video has UYVY (4:2:2) codec, since opencv can't read that format, I want to convert the codec to an RGB color model, I readed about ffmpeg and I want to know if it's possible to get this done with it ? if not if you a suggestion I'll be thankful.

Comment: `UYVY` is one of the [popular] pixel formats. You can definitely read from this file using DirectShow API, all the standard methods. Conversion into RGB is built into Windows. It is hard to tell why you cannot use the file you created.

Comment: I know to read but I don't know how to convert it `

Comment: I never heard of **RBB**, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [I explained to you before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838999/176769), OpenCV can read some formats of YUV, including **UYVY** (thanks to  FFmpeg/GStreamer). So I believe the `cv::Mat` you get from the camera is already converted to the BGR color space which is what OpenCV uses by default.

I modified my [previous program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838999/176769) to store the first frame of the video as PNG:

```
cv::Mat frame;
if (!cap.read(frame)) 
{
    return -1;
}            

cv::imwrite("mat.png", frame);

for(;;)
{
 // ...
```

And the image is perfect. Executing the command `file` on *mat.png* reveals:

```
mat.png: PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

A more accurate test would be to dump the entire `frame.data()` to the disk and open it with an image editor. If you do that keep in mind that the R and B channels will be switched.